Showing $\left(\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx\right)^2 \leq \int_{1}^{\infty} x^2 (f(x))^2 dx$ for continuous, non-negative $f$
Here is the question I am thinking about:

$(a)$ Suppose $f : [1, \infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is continuous. Show that $$\left(\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx\right)^2 \leq  \int_{1}^{\infty} x^2 (f(x))^2 dx.$$
$(b)$ For which continuous functions $f : [1, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is the inequality in $(a)$ an equality with both sides finite?

(from Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th edition, by Sheldon Axler)
I am not sure how I should prove this, I am guessing that I should use Cauchy Schwartz inequality but I am not sure how. Also, the improper integral is hindering me.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Remember that $x^2$ is harmless since it is greater or equal then zero.

Hint: Write $f(x)=(xf(x))\cdot\frac{1}{x}$ and use Cauchy-Schwartz.

@AleK3 the equality with zero might harm, am I correct?

@Mark will the improper integral affect me?

@Intuition If you are not sure you can do it directly on improper integral (which is a good thing, you shouldn't do things that you aren't sure are correct) then work with integrals from $1$ to $N$, and then take $N\to\infty$.

I mean is Cauchy Schwartz correct for  infinite dimensional spaces also?@Mark

Which norm should I use in Cauchy Schwartz? @Mark how is the inner product defined in this case?

@Intuition yes, in general you cannot expect an equality.

Please don't use tags which don't fit to the question. I removed them.

@MartinBrandenburg the question is in a linear algebra book that is why I used the tag linear algebra.

@Mark what about part (b)

@AleK3 ‘s solution is quite intuitive for solving only (a), but I think @Mark‘s solution is logical to solve both (a) and (b), since it’s asking the equality condition of the inequality.

@RDK can you elaborate more on $(b)$ please? How Mark's solution solve (b)?

You need to check under which conditions there is equality in Cauchy-Schwarz. These conditions are very precise.

If you write $f(x)=u(x)p(x)$ where
$$
p(x)=\begin{cases}
1/x^2,\text{ for }x\ge 1,\\
0,\text{ for }x<1
\end{cases}
$$
then $p(x)$ is the density of some random variable $X$.
Let $Y=u(X)$, then the inequality you want to prove is
$$
(\mathbb E Y)^2\le \mathbb E Y^2
$$
which is the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in probability theory.
Finally, for (b), note that the above inequality is equivalent to
$$
\mathbb E [(Y-\mathbb E Y)^2]=\mathrm{Var}(Y)=\mathbb E Y^2-(\mathbb E Y)^2\ge 0
$$
so the equality is achieved only if $Y=\mathbb E Y$ a.s., that is $Y$ must be a constant, and thus $f(x)=c/x^2$ for some $c>0$.

What about letter $(b)$?

I still did not get it

I added part (b).
